# C++ Get all running processes and their titles

Tags: c++, api, winapi

I am currently working on a project in C++ and what i want to do is to take all of the running available proceses and with them their titles , but currently I'm able only to track their handlers and count them and no to take their title.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam);
int i;
string hwndTitle;
LPTSTR WindowTitle;
int length = 0;
int getHWND()
{
    std::cout << "Finding all open windows\n";
    if(EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0)) {
        std::cout << i << " windows are open\n"<<hwndTitle<<"\n"<<"Call was successful...\n" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
    } else {
        std::cout << "Call was unsuccessful...\n" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
    }

    return 0;
} 

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    i++;
    HWND WindowHandle;
    WindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
    length = GetWindowTextLength (hWnd);
    hwndTitle = GetWindowText(hWnd , WindowTitle , length); 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not all processes have windows or titles. What do you want to do with those?

Comment: i'm working on a like taskmanager application .I's a simple header.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Problems include: `WindowTitle` is never allocated. `GetWindowText` doesn't return a `string`. The callback function receives a `HWND`, thus  `WindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow()` is counterproductive. Also: what does `.I's a simple header.` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is misusing `GetWindowText()`.  You are not allocating any memory for it to fill in, and it does not return a `std::string` or even a `char*`/`TCHAR*`, like your code is assuming.  And even if you were using it correctly, you are outputting only the last window title that is assigned to `hwndTitle` instead of concatenating multiple titles together.

Try something more like this instead:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam);

int getHWND()
{
    std::cout << "Finding all open windows" << std::endl;
    int i = 0;
    if (EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM) &i)) {
        std::cout << i << " windows are open\n" << "Call was successful...\n" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Call was unsuccessful...\n" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
} 

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int *i = (int*) lParam;
    ++(*i);
    int length = GetWindowTextLengthA(hWnd);
    std::vector<char> WindowTitle(length+1);
    length = GetWindowTextA(hWnd, &WindowTitle[0], length); 
    if (length > 0) {
        WindowTitle[length] = 0;
        std::cout << &WindowTitle[0] << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "(none)" << std::endl;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam);

int getHWND()
{
    std::cout << "Finding all open windows" << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::string> WindowTitles;
    if (EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM) &WindowTitles)) {
        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = WindowTitles.begin(); i != WindowTitles.end(); ++i) {
            if (!i->empty()) {
                std::cout << *i << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "(none)" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << WindowTitles.size() << " windows are open\n" << "Call was successful...\n" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Call was unsuccessful...\n" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
} 

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::vector<std::string> *WindowTitles = (std::vector<std::string>*) lParam;
    int length = GetWindowTextLengthA(hWnd);
    std::string WindowTitle(length+1, '\0');
    length = GetWindowTextA(hWnd, &WindowTitle[0], length); 
    WindowTitle.resize(length);
    WindowTitles->push_back(WindowTitle);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: @IInspectable: First, you don't know how the OP will be using the strings after containing them.  The original code was using `std::string` so I stayed with that and just removed the `TCHAR` dependency. If the OP wants to switch to Unicode, just replace `std::string` with `std::wstring` and use `GetWindowText(Length)W()`. Second, in this example, the Windows console does not support outputting Unicode strings very well (there are tons of questions about that, so I won't reiterate the issues here).

Comment: Console output is an artifact, used for debugging only.